Scrolling down the list of translation items often gets stuck before reaching the end
Describe the bug
When using the Translation tab in multiple pages mode, with the "Used Strings Only" filter enabled, scrolling down the list of translation items often gets stuck before reaching the end. It seems related to an issue with the infinite scroll functionality, which does not load items as expected.

Steps to reproduce

Go to the Translation tab in the application.
Select All Pages.
Enable the filter "Used Strings Only".
Scroll to the bottom of the translation items list.
Observe that scrolling is blocked before reaching the last items.


Expected behavior
The list should allow scrolling to display all items without interruption or blocking. If infinite scroll is active, it should function seamlessly and load additional items as the user reaches the bottom.

SurveyJS version: 1.12.10

Additional context
Is it possible to disable infinite scrolling in this context or to take control of the code to fix this issue, or could it be fixed to ensure smooth scrolling and proper loading of all elements? This issue significantly affects usability when working with large translation datasets.

The steps to reproduce would be useful if we had access to the app, but we do not, so the steps don't mean much to us. Can you provide either a runnable demo of the issue or include the code necessary to reproduce the issue within the question?  See how to create an MCVE

Most likely it can be reproduced in our online demo - https://surveyjs.io/create-free-survey
But probably SO is not a right place to post SurveyJS bugs here, here is the customer support portal  link - https://surveyjs.answerdesk.io/
